# Display converted XML output array result using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I'm trying to display a text list from a specific array output of a converted XML file.

The array looks like this:

```
["ServiceTerms"]=> array(1) { ["Included"]=>
```

I want the results of what's "Included" to be listed as bullet points in a webpage, using PHP.

I came up with something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://www.domain.com/convertedaxmlfile.php");
echo $xml['Included'];
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this is array not object echo $xml['Included'];

Comment: you said that The array looks like this: then why you trying to access as object . access it as array $xml['Included'];

Comment: Okay, I changed as requested but I get a parser error: Start tag expected, '<' not found